# Unity ゲーム開始3秒後アイテムを出現させるコードを書いたのですが(11,10): error CS0103: The name 'invoke' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity3d

以下のコードを実行するとエラーが出るのですが、解決策が分かりません。
どなたか教えてくださると幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
(11,10): error CS0103: The name 'invoke' does not exist in the current context
```

**現状のソースコード**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ItemPrefab;

    void Start()
    {
         invoke("Call", 3f);
    }

    void Call()
    { 
            GameObject Item = Instantiate(ItemPrefab);
            Item.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 10, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問本文はプログラムのみを書く場所ではありません。是非本文を [edit] して詳細を書いてみてください =)

Comment: `invoke`の`i`が小文字だからかも？ [【Unity】スクリプトの処理の実行タイミングを操作する](https://qiita.com/toRisouP/items/e402b15b36a8f9097ee9)

Comment: 先の方のコメントのとおり、基本的にUnityScriptの関数名はC#なのでは大文字はじまりです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google翻訳
(11,10): error CS0103: 「invoke」という名前は現在のコンテキストに存在しません

ということです。

Comment: invokeの「i」を大文字の「I」にしたら直りました！　皆さんありがとうございました